# Number LI's using jQuery

Tags: jquery, numbers, html-lists

I have an ordered list, but I want to number is manually in a separate `span` tag than use the default `list-style: decimal;`

```
<ol>
 <li><span>1</span> item 1</li>
 <li><span>2</span> item 2</li>
</ol>
```

How can I achieve this using jQuery?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$(function() {
  $("ol > li").each(function(i, n) {
    $(this).prepend("<span>" + (i+1) + "</span> ");
  });
});
```

You'll need to disable the standard markers too:

```
ol { list-style-type: none; }
```

Adjust as required.

Comment: Heavier than air flying machines.

Comment: Oh, just one problem, it starts from 0, how do I make it to start from 1? Thansk!

Comment: Er, the example above starts at 1. That's why it's (i+1).