# jQuery: Add Numbers into an Ordered List

Tags: jquery

I would like to use jQuery to make this:

```
<ol>
 <li>item a</li>
 <li>item b</li>
</ol>
<ol>
 <li>item c</li>
 <li>item d</li>
 <li>item e</li>
</ol>
```

…become this:

```
<ol>
 <li><span>1</span> item a</li>
 <li><span>2</span> item b</li>
</ol>
<ol>
 <li><span>1</span> item c</li>
 <li><span>2</span> item d</li>
 <li><span>3</span> item e</li>
</ol>
```

([This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1571024/number-lis-using-jquery) doesn't work for when there are multiple `ol`s on the page; the number would increment across the `ol`s instead of starting from 1 for each individual `ol`.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Or like this:

```
$('ol > li').each(function() {
    $(this).prepend("<span>" + ($(this).index() +1) + "</span>");
});
```

Reference: [`prepend()`](http://api.jquery.com/prepend/), [`index()`](http://api.jquery.com/index/)

Answer (score 3):

You could do something like this (since jQuery 1.4+, [`.prepend()`](http://api.jquery.com/prepend/) takes a function):

```
​$("ol").each(function() {
    $("li", this).prepend(​​​​​​​​function(i) {
        return $("<span />", {text: i+ 1 });
     });
});​
```

[You can see a working demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/mWcy3/)

Or, even shorter, but less efficient:

```
$("ol li").prepend(function() {
   return $("<span />", {text: $(this).index() +1 });
});​
```

[You can see that demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/thbgQ/)

Comment: +1, but you need to concatenate in a space character. `(i+1) + ' '` and `($(this).index() +1) + ' '`

Comment: @patrick - I agree for the example (actually the space is after the `<span>` in it)...but I'd do this in CSS If I were the OP, more consistent and better than doing it in javascript imo.

Comment: Good points. I had the space positioned incorrectly, and I agree that CSS would be a better way to space the appended numbers.

Answer (score 2):

Probably not the best solution, but it gets the job done :

```
​$('ol').each(function() {
    $(this).children('li').each(function(i) {
       $(this).prepend(' ' + (i+1) + ' '); 
    });
});​​
```

Comment: Where are the `<span>` tags? OP may intend to use them for styling.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("ol").each
(
    function ()
    {
        $("li", this).each
        (
            function (i)
            {
                $(this).prepend("<span>" + (i+1) + "</span>" );
            }
        );
    }
);
```