# How to count <li> using .each() in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I am trying to number each li like

```
 1 of n
 2 of n
 3 of n
 ......
 n of n
```

I am able to number each li like 1 , 2 ,3 but how to make 1 of 3

Here is a [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Vicky_Anand/PX6Sg/) that I created by referring to [**This Link**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1571024/number-lis-using-jquery)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use with:

```
$("ul > li").length
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/AXerh/)**

**Complete Code:**

```
var len=$("ul > li").length;
$("ul > li").each(function(i, n) {
 $(this).prepend("<span>" + (i+1) + " of "+  len +" </span> ");
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the easy and fast answer will accept the answer :)

Comment: `$("ul > li")` cache this like AP Johnny, This would do dom look up for every iterations.. :)

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy yes got it its a beter way to do it :)

Comment: @MilindAnantwar okay I am pretty new to this and besides I am just using for an image carousel maximum images are like 40 . I gues it will not effect much but for huge list I think `var len=$("ul > li").length;` is better way . :)

Comment: @Vikram: indeed yes :)

Comment: Note that this counts **all** the li elements in the page, so if there is more than one UL list, or the list has sub–levels (i.e. nested UL elements), the count may not suit. Also, if there are only UL elements in the page, then UL > LI is redundant since LI elements can only be children of UL or OL elements.

Comment: @RobG yes I was about to ask this question my page has different ul>li so how should I catch the one I want to add the numbers  ? . Should I use class selector somehow ?

Comment: You should use its parent while creating the selector. In your case you can use `$('#pageone li').length`

Comment: @MilindAnantwar I tried ` var $lis = $(" ul > li").find('.yo1');` but did not work whats wrong in this ? ... btw thanks

Comment: Okay got ya ` var $lis = $("#pageone").find('ul > li');` worked I need to search inside the parent div  oops thanks again :)

Comment: `$('#pageone li')` would be more efficient.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the length property of the jQuery object to find out the number of elements in it

```
$(function () {
    var $lis = $("ul > li"),
        len = $lis.length;
    $lis.prepend(function (i, n) {
        return "<span>" + (i + 1) + " of " + len + "</span> "
    });
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/fr5KY/)

Answer (score 1):

`.size` also work for this

```
$("ul > li").size()  //deprecated
```

but it is deprecated after jQuery 1.8.

so go for it

```
$("ul > li").length //prefered
```